# Narrow down a type of record with explicit field declarations

Tags: ocaml

I'm facing a problem that I need to narrow down the type

```
type 'a poly = {field1: 'a; field2: int}
```

I want to declare a new type

```
type mono = string poly = {field1: string; field2: int}
```

But when I try to do this I get an error

> This variant or record definition does not match that of type
> Base.string poly They have different arities.

However, the following definition does not cause errors:

```
type mono = string poly
```

I feel like I'm missing something, but the goal is to explicitly state the equality of these types.
I understand that my approach is too naive, but I hope it will give you an understanding of the problem.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of doing this? Justc hecking that this isn't an XY problem.

Comment: I'm working with the visitors syntax extension, and I need to redefine the polymorphic type `'a poly = {field1: 'a; ..} ` into a monomorphic ` type mono = {field1: certain_type; ..} `, equivalent to ` certain_type poly`, with access to the fields so that I can annotate one of them as `[ @opaque ]` (which is actually why I'm trying to achieve this, because in polymorphic=true mode I can't annotate polymorphic types with `[ @opaque ]` )

Comment: In general, I want to be able to write something equivalent to
`type 'a poly = {field1: 'a; ..}`
`type mono = certain_type poly = {field1: certain_type; ..}`,  so that I can replace certain_type poly with mono in other defined types

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a type without constructors, such as:

```
type mono = string poly
```

you are declaring a new name for an existing type. So this type `mono` is the same type as `poly` with string as its parameter.

When you declare a type with constructors, such as:

```
type mono = string poly = {field1: string; field2: int}
```

you are declaring a new type. This cannot be the same as any other type, by definition. So the part of this declaration saying that the type is the same as `string poly` is rejected.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! Is it possible to somehow access the fields of a `mono` when declaring it?

Comment: This is incorrect? Re-exporting a nominal type is allowed: `type 'a opt = 'a option = None | Some of 'a` works fine. What is not allowed is to modify a re-exported type definition.